# Explicitly calling a destructor when you only have a shared_ptr to the base class?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class `Base` and a subclass `Derived`.  I have a `shared_ptr` to an instance typed as `Base` (ie, `shared_ptr<Base>`).  How do I explicitly call the destructor of whatever the underlying class is, using this `shared_ptr`?

Obviously, doing something like this would be unsafe and illegal:

```
shared_ptr<Base> ref_; // defined somewhere
ref_->~Derived();
```

If I do `ref_->~Base()`, will it call the destructor of the `Derived` class?

Comment: Why? This seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Just [`reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) the `shared_ptr` and let it do its job. Make sure the `Base` destructor is `virtual`, then the correct destructor will be called when all `shared_ptr` references to the held object are cleared.

Comment: XY problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You should not explicitly call the destructor of a type which you do not own. By definition, if you have a `shared_ptr<T>`, that `T` is owned by the `shared_ptr`, not you. The semantics of shared ownership decide when the `T` is destroyed. That's the contract you entered into when you wrapped that `T` in the `shared_ptr`, or when you you were given the `shared_ptr`. And violating that contract is bad.

Also, unless you created the `shared_ptr<T>` itself, it is entirely possible that the `shared_ptr` doesn't own a `T`. It can instead own a `U` which itself owns the `T` which you have access to. So that's a second reason why trying to destroy the contents of a `shared_ptr` is wrong.

But in any case, calling the destructor of a base class will destroy the eventual derived class only if the base class destructor is `virtual`.